# Related to Scheduling: aging

Tags: operating-system, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

Can any one guide how to implement Process Aging?
I would Like to know on what **factors** does this Aging factor depend on?
According to me, it should depend on present priority and average waiting time.
How do I implement averaging waiting time?

Can any one please give clear idea on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process aging should depend only on the waiting time (according to the original concept) of the process. Based on its original idea, the priority of a process will be increased accordingly to the time it is waiting in the ready queue.

Answer (score 0):

read the process arrival time, burst time, process id, priority from the text file and calculate the average waiting time and show the cpu utilization of each cycle like this,

```
Time 1 P3 arrives
Time 1 P3 runs
Time 2 P5 arrives
Time 2 P3 runs
Time 10 P1 arrives
Time 10 P3 runs
Time 13 P3 finishes
Time 13 P5 runs
Time 16 P4 arrives
Time 16 P5 runs
Time 53 P5 finishes
Time 53 P1 runs
Time 82 P1 finishes
Time 82 P4 runs
Time 112 P4 finishes
```